# Go modules replace with a specific version of a local module

Tags: go, go-modules

I have a `go.mod` file that looks like this:

```
module someName

go 1.13

require (
    .
    .
    golang.org/x/crypto v0.0.0-20190621222207-cc06ce4a13d4
    localpackage v0.0.0
)

replace localpackage => ../localpackage
```

This works just as expected! What I can't figure out is how can I add a certain version or commit hash to the `replace` directive!

For example:

```
replace localpackage => ../localpackage v1.0.0
```

or

```
replace localpackage => ../localpackage v0.0.0-20190731182444-35453ccff3d6
```

Doing this results in an error:

> replacement module directory path "../localpackage" cannot have version

The error is quite clear that I shouldn't add a version to a local replace. I checked the [wiki](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#when-should-i-use-the-replace-directive) but I couldn't find an answer!

#### The question:

Is it possible to add this kind of `replace`ment and how? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the error says: you cannot specify a version when the replace directive is pointed at a local folder. There is no guarantee and it is not a requirement that the replacement folder contains files of a versioning system, it is perfectly valid to just have "snaphots" of the Go sources. So in many cases it would have no meaning to specify a version.

However, if your local folder is a clone of a git repository for example, you may simply switch that to your intended version. E.g. execute a `git checkout v1.0.0` in that local folder to switch to that version, and that version will be used.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What would be the right way to enforce versioning while using a private module not hosted on github.com?

Comment: @Abdullah Maintain a separate folder for each version that needs to be used in the app.